# Sed: read from file and display in STDOUT

Tags: linux, sed

Learning sed, and I was using a live editor so I can experiment/see changes.

```
sed -nf '/START FROM HERE/,${/NEXTLINE/{n;p;q}}'
```

When trying to run the same code, on Linux, I receive error No such file or Directory when I execute as `./xxx.sed text0.txt`

I've tried a couple of things but I am not sure how to use sed like this.

Comment: `sed -nf '/START FROM HERE/,${/NEXTLINE/{n;p;q}}' test0.txt`

Comment: What is `xxx.sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` option means that the next argument is the name of a file containing the `sed` commands. So you need to put

```
/START FROM HERE/,${/NEXTLINE/{n;p;q}}
```

in the file `xxx.sed`. Then you do:

```
sed -nf xxx.sed test0.txt
```

If you want to be able to execute `xxx.sed` as a command, it needs a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nf
/START FROM HERE/,${/NEXTLINE/{n;p;q}}
```

Then you can make the file executable and do:

```
./xxx.sed file0.txt
```

Comment: Thank you properly setting up the shebang solved my issue.